# How to add an image to an anchor tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making an anchor tag look like a button by using an image, but it doesn't show anything in the browser.

This is my code so far...

**HTML**

```
<span>
    <a id="knapNyhed" href="file:///E:/Projekt_skolespil/hjemmeside/index.html"></a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.knapNyhed{
    background-image: pic/knap_nyhed_layout_00.png;
    width:226px;
    heigth: 50px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
```

Hope you can help with why I can't see my button

Answer (score 14):

You have to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` as `a` tags are set to `display:inline` by default and inline elements can't have a `width`, `height` or `margin`.

To get the background image working you have to add `url`. Please note that this url is relative to your css file.

```
#knapNyhed {
  display:block;
  background-image: url(pic/knap_nyhed_layout_00.png);
  width:226px;
  heigth: 50px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying the 'width'? It's rather unflexible having to set it to an exact number, and bad for mobile screens, because they won't resize below the specified width automatically.

Comment: You can set `width: 100%; max-width:226px` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to surrond your path to file with url()

like this:

```
background-image: url('pic/knap_nyhed_layout_00.png');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<span>
    <a id="knapNyhed" href="file:///E:/Projekt_skolespil/hjemmeside/index.html">text</a>
</span>
```

u you need your text between the >< like this

Comment: Can you explain further what you've changed to make it work? Which kind of text should be needed?